# removing lines that don't match by grep

Tags: grep, file-handling

I have a file containing gene names of interest (24423 genes), and another file containing the lengths to all the genes (41306 genes). I want the lengths only to the 24424 genes, but when I `grep` using `grep -wf file1 file2` or even `fgrep -Fwf file1 file2`, I get some excess genes, because some genes in my list may contain only the sense or the anti-sense strands, whereas if the reference file may contain both, and that is being reflected.

I want to know if there is a way to remove from the reference file (file2) all the lines that don't match?

Thank you.

P.S. The question is also on [biostars.org](https://www.biostars.org/p/299940/)

edit -

> file1

A1BG

A1BG-AS1

TSPAN6

MYB

MYB-AS1

> file2

A1BG      2941

A1BG-AS1      560

TSPAN6      7923

MYB-AS1      362

MYB-AS2      713

MYB-AS3      396

> desired_output

A1BG      2941

A1BG-AS1      560

TSPAN6      7923

MYB-AS1      362

> But I always get MYB-AS2 and MYB-AS3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat f1
A1BG
A1BG-AS1
TSPAN6
MYB
MYB-AS1
$ cat f2
A1BG      2941
A1BG-AS1      560
TSPAN6      7923
MYB-AS1      362
MYB-AS2      713
MYB-AS3      396

$ grep -Fwf f1 f2
A1BG      2941
A1BG-AS1      560
TSPAN6      7923
MYB-AS1      362
MYB-AS2      713
MYB-AS3      396
```

`grep` won't help here because `MYB` will match `MYB-` as `-` will work as word boundary

Use `awk` instead

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a' f1 f2
A1BG      2941
A1BG-AS1      560
TSPAN6      7923
MYB-AS1      362
```

- `NR==FNR{a[$1]; next}` build an array with first field from first file as keys
- `$1 in a` print lines from second file if first field is a key in the array. Entire field has to match
- See also http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ for more examples/explanation on this type of two file processing